# PHP Parse error on one computer but not on other

Tags: php

What causes the following error?

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in xx.php on line xxx
```

On the the line xxx there is only a closing php tag ie. `?>`

Important thing is that this error occurs on one computer but not on the other computer? (eg. if i run the same php file on the local host on 2 computer). Why is that so? Is it something to do with php.ini settings or some other settings? Because if its an error, it should show on both computers? How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: what is the configuration differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the php.ini file in both server

if ini setting short_open_tag is configured , u can use `<? ?>`

otherwise it will show parse error

Comment: +1 because this is probably the answer - the only other point is that there are slight syntax differences between major release versions - if one host is running PHP 4 and one is running PHP 5, this can happen - also between PHP 5.2 and PHP 5.3. Also, some versions are slightly more forgiving of missing `}`s and `;`s than others.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was because of short_open_tag.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a short tag issue, replace all `<? with <?php`

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance you have open php tags which look like `<?`

If so, replace them with `<?php`

Answer (score 0):

Check your code, looks like you are missing a } somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is another char behind your closing tag. If it is a php file with only php code you can remove the closing tag ?>.